# Get minimum value field name using aggregation in django

Tags: python, django, min, django-aggregation

I have a model with some fields like below

```
class Choclate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

So i want to get the field name that has the `lowest price`  value, 
so in order to get the `lowest price` value, we can do like below using `Aggregations`

```
from django.db.models import Avg, Max, Min

choclates = Choclate.objects.all()
lowest_price = choclates.aggregate(Min('price'))
```

So finally how to get the `field name`, that related to lowest price value in django ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try below code to get exact thing you want

```
>>> from django.db.models import Min
>>> Choclate.objects.filter().values_list('name').annotate(Min('price')).order_by('price')[0]
(u'First1', 10)
>>>
```

`First1` is the field name having `price = 10` which is lowest value.

[Documentation Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset)

Comment: k thanks thats what i want, also is there any way to find that if all the price values are equal, i mean if there are 4 choclate records, i need to check whether all the four records have same price value , is it possible ?

Comment: yep sure, i hope u found my above comment/doubt ?

Comment: if i will try i will put some if else condition after fetching all 4 records from db .i did not find and specific query for this

Comment: The annotate here does nothing, this is equivalent to `Choclate.objects.filter().order_by('price').values_list('name')[0]`

Comment: This query actually have a bad performance on large tables.

Answer (score 4):

If you pass the `Min` as positional argument, then the field's name is `price__min`. Otherwise, if you pass it as keyword argument, i.e. `aggregate(my_min=Min('price'))`, then it will be available with the same name as the argument, in this case `my_min`. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset)

Answer (score 4):

For Min and Max you may order your values (QuerySet result) and grab the first() and last():

```
chocolate_list = Chocolate.objects.values_list('name', 'price')
min = chocolate_list.order_by('price').first()
max = chocolate_list.order_by('price').last()
```

PS: Remove the filter() if you are not assigning nothing. With values_list() you are implicitly instancing the QuerySet class

Answer (score 4):

Usage of what @Maciej Gol said:

```
from django.db.models import Min    

lowest_price = Chocolate.objects.values('price').aggregate(Min('price'))['price__min']
```

Comment: This does give OP the `lowest price`, but does not give him the `field name`.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [Jcc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58526448/11875147) and [Luciano's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7632019/luciano), the **solution for the exact OP's question** would be the following.

### Code

```
cheapest_choclate = Choclate.objects.values_list('name', 'price').order_by('price')[0]
lowest_price = cheapest_choclate['price']
cheapest_choclate_name = cheapest_choclate['name']
```

### Explanation

Using `Choclate.objects`, you obtain all objects of class Choclate from the DB.

Using `.values_list('name', 'price')`, you create a QuerySet with a list of tuples where each tuple contains the 'name' and 'price' of each object - e.g. `[('Sweet', 79),('Bitter', 49), ('Spicy', 69)]`.

Using `.order_by('price')`, you order the tuples in the list using the price - e.g. `[('Bitter', 49), ('Spicy', 69), ('Sweet', 79)]`.

Using `[0]`, you select the first tuple from the list. This tuple contains the name and price of the cheapest choclate. You could also use `.first()` as suggested by [Jcc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58526448/11875147). However, I like the `[0]` approach more as it can easily be changed to something else if needed - e.g. "second cheapest" choclate could be obtained using `[1]`.

Lastly, you can obtain the price and name of the cheapest choclate from the first tuple using `cheapest_choclate['price']` and `cheapest_choclate['name']`.