# select special items from foregin key in django

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-views

I have two models

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    averageRating = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    ratingCount = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

and

```
class VariantProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mainPrice = models.IntegerField()
    discountPrice = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

this means different variant of products have different prices.

**I need the variant of each product that have minimum mainPrice**

in SQL i think this code works for my purpose

```
        SELECT *, min(discountPrice) as minPrice
        FROM variant GROUP BY product
```

but I don't know how can I get this result in Django

Comment: `VariantProduct.objects.all().order_by('-mainPrice')` to order your data lowest price to high or if you want more accurate check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19678250/14457833)

Comment: No... I don't want just a simple sort :)
the link you mentioned , only return smallest price... not minimum price of each product
**I need the variant of each product that have minimum mainPrice**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an annotation to attach the minimum price of VariantProducts attached to Product objects:

```py
from django.db.models import Min

Product.objects.annotate(minimum_main_price=Min('variantproduct__mainPrice'))
```